# PHP: using imagick to create a sentence out of separate images?

Tags: php, imagick

Basically trying to follow this example: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/

So lets say I have a folder (fonts) with all the letters and numbers in separate images.

like so:

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
etc...
A.png
B.png
C.png
etc...
```

On my page, I have an input field where I can type a sentence in and then click a submit button....

And then this page will lead to a php page where for each letter or number that's written in the input field, the imagick will pick an appropriate image from that folder (fonts) and then append them to a background image to create the sentence in an image format....

Could someone please advise on this and maybe some basic examples if possible to get me started?

Any help would be appreciated.